# How to put a for loop on a range

Tags: excel, vba

[image: This is what my excel sheet looks like]

So basically I'm trying to select a bunch of cells, transpose them then move on to the next three.

This is what the code would look like for one set. I have a lot and changing each manually would take too much time so how could I run a loop on this to suppose take the first three rows, transpose then move onto the next?
Now if i took the enitre range and transposed it, it would make seperate columns for each male female and total. What im trying to do is to transpose each and post them in one column.

```
Range("B20:C21").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("D19").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Range("B22:C23").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("D21").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Why did you copy `B20:C21` and then `B22:C23`? Why not `B20:C23`?

Comment: @Jeremy Because in the B column what ive got is Male, Females then Totals for one category, followed by M F T again for the next category. What im trying to do is to be able to sum so that I have the males in one row and the females etc. If i took the entire range it would transpose it like this: Male Female Total Male Female Total etc. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what it would look like - I'm not able to visualise what you're saying

Comment: @Jeremy check now. this is what it looks like now. I want to transpose it such that the male is in column lets say D, female in E, and totals in F

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but should work or at least be simple enough to to give you a good starting point.

```
sub doit
   dim src as range, dest as range
   set src = range("b20:c21")
   set dest = range("d19")
   do 
      src.copy
      dest.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
             False, Transpose:=True
      set src = src.offset(2,0)
      set dest = dest.offset(2,0)
   loop until src.row > 200   'update according to your needs
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just before I give a solution, I want to be sure this is what you are looking for, based off your explanation above:

[image]